# Div height without content

Tags: jquery, css, html

[image]

Hi,

I'm really don't know how I can fix this isse because I've some pages without any content but the structure of the template leaves the rest of the page blank.

I've tried to apply some different techniques with css or jquery and I couldn't find a solution. Could some one help me?

this is the code for the moment:

```
html {
height: 100%;
}

body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
height: 100%;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: 'Tahoma' sans-serif;
color: #1c1c1c;
}

#wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
}


/* Header  */

header {

width:100%;
background:#454545;
 height: 100%;

}

#main {  
overflow:hidden;
}


 .content {
width:86%;
    height: 100%;
padding:10px;
margin-left:5px;
float:left;
background:#FFF;


}  

 .sidebar {  
padding:1px;
width:12%;
background:#FF8500; 
float:left;
padding-bottom: 30000px;
    margin-bottom: -30000px;

}

footer {
clear: both;
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
height: 3em;
margin-top: -3em;
padding:10px;
background:#000;
text-align:right;
color:#FFF; 
}
```

I share the html: http://jsfiddle.net/7r2SG/2/

Comment: are you able to post a fiddle?

Comment: The basic html structure would help.

Comment: Try adding a min-height style tag with specific number of pixels to the css.  When you work in %, no content will push it to its smallest value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Fixed mistakes.
Basically to set the height of an element, the parent heights need to be known first.

You will see the height removed from the header (as it tries to go full page height), and height 100% added to all parent elements e.g wrapper, main, body, html.
min-height 100% added to main element too.

```
html {
     height: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Tahoma' sans-serif;
    color: #1c1c1c;
}

#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height:100%;
}


/* Header  */

header {

 width:100%;
 background:#454545;


}

#main {  
   overflow:hidden;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}

.nav {
    background:#FF8500;
    margin:0;
    padding:2px;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;

}

.nav ul {

    padding:2px 10px;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    padding: 0;
    margin:5px 0;
}

.nav li a {
    text-align: left;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: list-item;
    padding: 5px;
}
 .content {
    width:86%;
    height: 100%;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left:5px;
    float:left;
    background:#FFF;
}  

 .sidebar {  
    padding:1px;
    width:12%;
    background:#FF8500; 
    float:left;
    padding-bottom: 30000px;
    margin-bottom: -30000px;
}

footer {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    height: 3em;
    margin-top: -3em;
    padding:10px;
    background:#000;
    text-align:right;
    color:#FFF; 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? I believe it solved the problem you asked, i don't know why two days later you unaccept it. At least give it a +1 if it is a "good solution".

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to move the content area down to make it larger? If so, add this style to #main:

min-height: 500px;

Comment: Not recommended, this is not a scalable approach. While this does work, what would be the effects on a screen with 1000px height etc.

Comment: you could use javascript to set the min-height value once the page is loaded.

Comment: Why add unnecessary code, when you can set it once in css. (band-aid approaches are not good coding techniques).

Comment: If he is just trying to make the left side bar show up and have a little "padding", then I don't see the problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to be tough to achieve that vertical space using floats for your columns w/o javascript- here is a pure css solution using `position:absolute` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/cKtg2/